# Applying matplotlib color map to opencv image

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, colormap

I'm trying to apply a colormap from matplotlib to a OpenCv Image (I know I can use other libraries, but I'm using OpenCv for other things).

I can apply it and show it with the following script:

```
import cv2
from matplotlib.pylab import cm

def colorize(image, colormap):
    im = cv2.imread(image)
    im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    colorized = colormap(im)
    cv2.imshow("colorized", colorized)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.imwrite("colorized.jpg", colorized)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    colorize(sys.argv[1], cm.jet)
```

It does fine, but the "colorized.jpg" image is black.

I suppose I have to convert it from a 3 color + alpha channel to a 3 channel image, but no idea how.

Is there a way to save the image shown in the `imshow()` call correctly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`imwrite` expects color values in the range [0,255]. However, the colormap returns color values in the range [0,1]. Thus, this gives the desired result:

```
cv2.imwrite("colorized.jpg", colorized*255)
```

Comment: Are you sure? It works for me. Have you seen the multiplication by `255`?